# How to reset an unknown Google account?

Tags: google-account

how do I reset a google acct if the info is unknown. I was given a Samsung G7 phone. but I don't know the google email or password. Im wanting to reset it & add my google information to it.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset" here? Do you mean to remove that account from the device? If not, then resetting an unknown account's credentials  is something we don't support (because the account can be misused later) and neither it is on-topic here (Android independent).

Comment: There's [an anonymous suggested edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/207898) that conflicts with the original revision: The OP was given a Samung G7, and the editor claimed they lost it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to open the mobile

**To remove old Account**

1. Go to settings -> Accounts -> Google **or** settings -> sync -> Google depending on your system
2. Tap on the account you want to remove
3. Tap more -> remove account

**To Add New Account**

1. Go to settings -> Accounts **or** settings -> sync depending on your system
2. Click Add Account
3. Select Google and add your google account.

You can also add new google account from gmail app.

Hope this helps.